# "Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address" issue

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I don't know what happened, but one day when I got up and `git push` my changes it gave:

```
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address '140.82.112.4'
Offending key for IP in /Users/joyliu/.ssh/known_hosts:13
Matching host key in /Users/joyliu/.ssh/known_hosts:16
```

It seems like I'm not able to connect to Github. I Googled the fix and did `sed -i '13d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts` to delete line 13 but then it shows the same error with a different line number.

It also happened when I did `git pull`.

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

======== Update ========

After `ssh-keygen -R github.com` and `ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`, it still doesn't work somehow... It gave:

```
(base) ➜  liuzz10.github.io git:(master) ssh-keygen -R github.com
# Host github.com found: line 17
# Host github.com found: line 18
# Host github.com found: line 19
# Host github.com found: line 20
/Users/joyliu/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /Users/joyliu/.ssh/known_hosts.old
(base) ➜  liuzz10.github.io git:(master) ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-4b034cc8
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-4b034cc8
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-4b034cc8
(base) ➜  liuzz10.github.io git:(master) git pull
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address '140.82.112.4'
Offending key for IP in /Users/joyliu/.ssh/known_hosts:13
Matching host key in /Users/joyliu/.ssh/known_hosts:18
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
(base) ➜  liuzz10.github.io git:(master) git push
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address '140.82.112.4'
Offending key for IP in /Users/joyliu/.ssh/known_hosts:13
Matching host key in /Users/joyliu/.ssh/known_hosts:18
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
To github.com:liuzz10/liuzz10.github.io.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:liuzz10/liuzz10.github.io.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 34):

If you are getting the following error:

```bash
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address 'IP_ADDRESS'
```

I would recommend to do the following:

```bash
$ ssh-keygen -R github.com
```

If that does not work then remove the IP itself from known-host:

```bash
$ ssh-keygen -R IP_ADDRESS
```

This should would fix your issue.

Comment: the extra step of removing the indicated ip address was required in my case. thanks

Comment: Yep, I too confirm. The IP addresses need to be removed as well. Then just do "git pull" and follow the prompts to add the new IP to known_hosts automatically.

Answer (score 22):

[Answering the question about SSH host keys.]

You have 2 different host keys for `github.com` in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. The warning is about the 1st one. Remove both keys:

```
ssh-keygen -R github.com
```

and re-add the proper key(s):

```
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

This will add the current RSA and ECDSA keys.

Comment: Hi phd, thank you for helping me! It seems like the command works but the problem is still there somehow. Please see my update in the original post.

Comment: @Joy Somehow it seems `ssh-keygen -R github.com` doesn't remove line 13.

Comment: @phd Additional step was required for me to rip out all of the old github ip address keys: `ssh-keygen -R 140.82.113.4; ssh-keygen -R 140.82.113.3`

Comment: Thanks @SurpriseDog - keeping in mind the IPs can be different. I had `140.82.121.3` and `140.82.121.4` in my `known_hosts`. Cleaning up all the `github.com` and `140.82.x.x` entries + running `ssh-keyscan` as mentioned by @phd worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

This is recently started after github has rotated their [RSA SSH host key](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/) at approximately 05:00 UTC on March 24, 2023. Almost everyone has started seeing the same issue. To remove the warning as suggested by the reference post run below command

```
ssh-keygen -R github.com
```

or you can update your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file to remove the entry manually.

To automatically add the key to your known host and remove the warning permanently for github.com run below command

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/meta | jq -r '.ssh_keys | .[]' | sed -e 's/^/github.com /' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score 4):

File `~/.ssh/known_hosts` may contain same key for different IP addresses so first **remove all entries** that have same key as `github.com`, eg

```
github.com,192.30.252.130 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
140.82.114.4 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
140.82.112.3 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
```

and then insert valid key for `github.com` hostname

```
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

To verify github IP addresses [read documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-githubs-ip-addresses) or simple type eg. `nslookup 140.82.112.3`

Finally you can verify result and connect to the server: `ssh git@github.com`. You should be able to connect without any confirmation about key.