# RSA host key for github.com differes from the key for the IP address (error re-appears after performing git push)

Tags: git, ssh, rsa, public-key-encryption, known-hosts

I understand this is due to the pub key change and followed the steps here to fix it:
[Why are connections to GitHub over SSH throwing an error "Warning: Remote Host Identification Has Changed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75830783/why-are-connections-to-github-over-ssh-throwing-an-error-warning-remote-host-i)

However, everytime I perform the git push command, this message re-appears and I have to update my known_hosts file again.

Anyone else ran into this issue?

Comment: Try `ssh-keygen -R github.com && ssh-keygen -R 140.82.113.4 && ssh-keygen -R 140.82.113.3 && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` See https://stackoverflow.com/q/76187211/7976758

Comment: Already did that and it works fine with pull. The problem is when I push changes. Then I get this error again on both push and pull. I can confirm it with "yes" in the console, but it takes an extra step.

Comment: Edit `known_hosts`. Find the entries for GitHub and remove those lines.

Comment: @phd - the details about `known_hosts` are not part of the post. Details matter to get good answers. You are assuming that `known_hosts` is hashed. I am assuming it is not. The question should be updated so that we are not assuming anything.

Comment: Not hashed and already tried that - as mentioned in the description, the issue gets fixed until I run git push specifically.

Comment: Diff the before and after changes to known_hosts. That might provide a clue. Add those details to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there were some additional entries with the same IP and key from github in my known_hosts file. I had to remove all of them manually.

```
github.com,192.30.252.130 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
140.82.114.4 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
140.82.112.3 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
```

Then ran the command to add a valid key

```
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

That fixed the issue for me.